# How can I fix up this Identity int on my DB table?

Tags: sql, identity

A week or so ago some data got imported into a db table. Simple table:

Id INT PK NOT NULL IDENTITY
Name VARCHAR(20)

Now, I noticed today that the first id starts at 0. Asking the kid, he was reseeding it during his testing. So the first entry was a zero. Was an accident.

I'm not sure how to best update the value. How can I push everything up one number? What pains me is that there's also some FK dependencies. If I have Cascade Update, should that fix the dependencies?

Also, should I update each number (however I do that??) from the top down .. eg. from the highest number, then +1. Then go down.

Comment: What DB software are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, why are you stressing?  ID=0 is complete valid, if a bit unusual.  (Note that Zero Is *NOT* `NULL`)

If you really want to get rid of the 0:

- add a dummy record,
- note it's ID,
- If there are foreign keys pointing to Record 0, update them to the dummy record.
- delete that record. (to advance the internal ID counter).
- Just change ID 0 to that value.

Comment: it's not that i'm stressing, it just that i like my id's all to start with 1 :) nice, clean db's.. all consistent :)